# I have a jQuery function written in layout , How can I call it from view?

Tags: jquery, layout, asp.net-mvc-5

I have Written a function in layout file in $(document).ready
and that function get a 2 parameter So I want to call it from some partial views but I get this error in browser console

And I also call it in this ways from partial view 

call it in $(document).ready of partial view

1. `window.parent().ajaxGetList('Index', 'form#groupFilterForm');`

   error is jquery-3.1.1.js:3856 Uncaught TypeError: window.parent() is not a function
2. `window.parent.ajaxGetList('Index', 'form#groupFilterForm');` 

   error is : jquery-3.1.1.js:3856 Uncaught TypeError: window.parent is not a function
3. `ajaxGetList('Index', 'form#groupFilterForm');`

   error is : jquery-3.1.1.js:3856 Uncaught TypeError: ajaxGetList is not a function

I have written ajaxGetList funtion in $(document).ready of Layout and try to call it from partial views

Comment: You can't access a function defined inside `$(document).ready...` from outside it

Comment: you can create another similar function with different name and put it outside document ready then call it .may be  this works